# Iterate through a nested dict inside of a list, with some missing keys

Tags: python, json

I need your guys' help on how to extract information from a nested dictionary inside a list. Here's the code to get the data:

```
import requests
import json
import time

all_urls = []
for x in range(5000,5010):
    url = f'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/{x}/full'
    all_urls.append(url)

all_responses = []
for page_url in all_urls:
    response = requests.get(page_url)
    all_responses.append(response)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(all_responses)

data = []
for i in all_responses:
    json_data = json.loads(i.text)
    data.append(json_data)

print(data)
```

The sample of the extracted data is as follows:

```
[{'status': 404,
  'type': 'BadResponseException',
  'message': 'Resource does not exist',
  'error': '404 on https://myanimelist.net/anime/5000/'},
 {'status': 404,
  'type': 'BadResponseException',
  'message': 'Resource does not exist',
  'error': '404 on https://myanimelist.net/anime/5001/'},
 {'data': {'mal_id': 5002,
   'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/5002/Bari_Bari_Densetsu',
   'images': {'jpg': {'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873.jpg',
     'small_image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873t.jpg',
     'large_image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873l.jpg'},
    'webp': {'image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873.webp',
     'small_image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873t.webp',
     'large_image_url': 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/4/58873l.webp'}},
   'trailer': {'youtube_id': None,
    'url': None,
    'embed_url': None,
    'images': {'image_url': None,
     'small_image_url': None,
     'medium_image_url': None,
     'large_image_url': None,
     'maximum_image_url': None}},
   'title': 'Bari Bari Densetsu',
   'title_english': None,
   'title_japanese': 'バリバリ伝説',
   'title_synonyms': ['Baribari Densetsu',
......
```

I need to extract the title from the list of data. Any help is appreciated! Also, any recommendation on a better/simpler/cleaner code to extract the json data from an API is also greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, no need to create multiple lists. You can do everything in one loop:

```
import requests
import json

data = []

for x in range(5000,5010):
    page_url = f'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/{x}/full'
    response = requests.get(page_url)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    data.append(json_data)

print(data)
```

Second, to address your problem, you have two options. You can use `dict.get`:

```
for dic in data:
    title = dic.get('title', 'no title')
```

Or use the `try/except` pattern:

```
for dic in data:
    try:
        title = dic['title']
    except KeyError:
        # deal with case where dict has no title
        pass
```

Comment: Sure no problem @mangarapaul.

Comment: Oh one more thing, I actually ran into a problem when trying to extract the title based on your solution. I tried using both methods but both of them return no title/nothing. Do you know why?

Comment: @mangarapaul probably because `'title'` isn't a top-level key. You'll probably need to do a little digging to figure out what level the `'title'` key is at. I might've misjudged its position from your answer. Play around a little. Try `dic['data']['title']` and stuff like that.

Comment: it works! It turns out 'data' is the top level key for title. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great to hear, no problem @mangarapaul if this answer was helpful to you, also consider clicking the checkmark beside the answer.